# Limit Python pickle to simple types

Tags: python, pickle

I need to serialize and transfer Python objects between interpreters, and pickle is an ideal choice. However, pickle allows the user of mu lib to serialize globa functions, classes (and their instances) and modules. However, these may not be present on the receiving end, e.g. this runs without any errors:

```py
def user_func():
    return 42
pickle.dumps({'function': user_func})
```

So: How can I convince pickle to reject anything that is not a built-in type (or with a similar restriction)?

JSON and other universal formats are not a really good solution, as pickle allows Python-native data types such as `set()` and data structures with circular/shared references.

Comment: would it matter if you sent complex structures and then discard them if pickle can't load them? since you're also saying that any built in type that is not native (needing some import) is also banned? stuff like datetime and regular expressions are still guranteed to be valid on the other side so wouldn't it make more sense to try to `pickle.loads` just in case you CAN load it?

Comment: Trying `pickle.loads` immediately should always work, and it may be too late after distributing the objects on network or storing them. User functions and classes could be checked by `loads` in a new python instance, but that seems a bit complicated, and still may use locally installed modules not present in the target python environment.

Comment: But I agree that allowing standard modules and types such as DateTime and regexes would not be a problem and may be useful, but that was not our original goal (and it may be difficult to draw the line between them and external libs). Thanks for the idea and suggestion, though!

Comment: i was actually asking why can't you use loads on the remote machine, but i guess that doesnt matter since i did some research and couldn't find a way to distinguish between types except for making a big list of objects you allow...

Comment: One reason why not load them there is simplicity, the other storage (loading much later). What can be done if I would be willing to list the allowed (builtin) modules or types?

Comment: you could make a function that compares the item to a predefined list, then recursively  iterate over any container to see if all the items in it are allowed

Comment: That seems fragile, and you would need to take care of reference loops and shared substructures ... An idea to explore later: make custom DIspatch table https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle-dispatch or use persistent_id as a visitor https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#pickle.Pickler.persistent_id

Comment: @AntiMatterDynamite: by the time you can compare the item, it has already been constructed. As in: a malicious `__init__` could have already been executed.

Comment: @Pieter the question is about transferring data between interpreters ... if one could intercept that inner process communication you would think he would have ways to run code on his own by then